# IllegalArgumentException when using weka.clusterers.HierarchicalClusterer

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, weka, hierarchical-clustering

I searched a lot, but I was not able to find any example code, which describes how to use the WEKA HierarchicalClusterer. Using the following C#-code gives me an IllegalArgumentException at "agg.buildClusterer(insts);".

```
weka.clusterers.HierarchicalClusterer agg = new weka.clusterers.HierarchicalClusterer();
agg.setNumClusters(NumCluster);
/*
Tag[] TAGS_LINK_TYPE = agg.getLinkType().getTags();
agg.setLinkType(new SelectedTag(1, TAGS_LINK_TYPE));
*/
agg.buildClusterer(insts);
for (int i = 0; i < insts.numInstances(); i++)
{
    int clusterNumber = agg.clusterInstance(insts.instance(i));
}
```

The StackTrace says:

```
at java.util.PriorityQueue..ctor(Int32 initialCapacity, Comparator comparator)
at weka.clusterers.HierarchicalClusterer.doLinkClustering(Int32 , Vector[] , Node[] )
at weka.clusterers.HierarchicalClusterer.buildClusterer(Instances data)
```

but no Message or InnerException is specified.
The varaible "insts" is an Instances-object, which only holds instances with an equal amount of numerical attributes.

Is anyone able to quickly find my error or please post/link some example code?
Further, is the setting of the LinkType (commented code) correct?

Thanks,
Björn

Comment: You might want to look into other applications. Weka has minimal support for clustering, and it's quite slow.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Any suggestions in particular for the C# developer in mind?  I think that that is the variable which makes us want Weka to work so badly on this task.

Comment: Weka isn't native C#, but Java. If you already use a Java-C# bridge, you might as well try other Java sofware.

Answer (score 0):

The HierarchicalClusterer class has a `TAGS_LINK_TYPE` attribute.  So like

```
agg.setLinkType(new SelectedTag(1, HierarchicalClusterer.TAGS_LINK_TYPE));
```

will achieve what you are after for setting the linking.  Now what on earth does that 1 mean?  From the javadocs we see what TAGS_LINK_TYPE contains:

```
 -L Link type (Single, Complete, Average, Mean, Centroid, Ward, Adjusted complete, Neighbor Joining)
  [SINGLE|COMPLETE|AVERAGE|MEAN|CENTROID|WARD|ADJCOMLPETE|NEIGHBOR_JOINING]
```

In general, your code looks ok for the C# case.  I see you don't set the distance metric in your example above and maybe you would want to do this?  I too use Weka as best I can with C# using IKVM.  I have found the dataset allowed for hierarchical clustering is not too large.  Maybe your dataset exceeds what WEKA can handled and you would avoid your error if you reduced the size of the dataset?